# MapStruct with groovy classes

Tags: groovy, mapstruct

I want to use the Mapstruct mapper on groovy classes with gradle.
The configuration in the build.gradle looks like in a Java project.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'

    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final' // if you are using mapstruct in test code
}
```

The problem is that the implementation classes for the mappers are not generated.
I tried also to apply different options for the groovy compile task, but it doesn't work.

```
compileGroovy {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.annotationProcessor
    // if you need to configure mapstruct component model
    options.compilerArgs << "-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=default"
    options.setAnnotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory( file("$projectDir/src/main/generated/groovy"))
}
```

Does anyone know if Mapstruct can work together with groovy classes and how I have to configure it?

Comment: Why would you need MapStruct in Groovy? what's your use-case?

Comment: Mapping between different Objects with the ability to specify some specific mapping rules within the MapStruct annotations. An example can be different property names in the classes or  sometimes I have to ignore null properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you can use this build:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.9'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
}

compileGroovy.groovyOptions.javaAnnotationProcessing = true
```

With this `Car` (slightly modified from their example)

```
import groovy.transform.Immutable

@Immutable
class Car {
    String make;
    int numberOfSeats;
    CarType type;
}
```

And this `CarDto` (again, slightly modified)

```
import groovy.transform.ToString

@ToString
class CarDto {

    String make;
    int seatCount;
    String type;
}
```

Then the only change you need to make in the `CarMapper` is to ignore the `metaClass` property that Groovy adds to objects:

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper
import org.mapstruct.Mapping
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers

@Mapper
interface CarMapper {
    CarMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CarMapper)

    @Mapping(source = "numberOfSeats", target = "seatCount")
    @Mapping(target = "metaClass", ignore = true)
    CarDto carToCarDto(Car car)
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
class Main {

    static main(args) {
        Car car = new Car("Morris", 5, CarType.SEDAN);

        CarDto carDto = CarMapper.INSTANCE.carToCarDto(car);

        println carDto
    }
}
```

Which prints out:

```
main.CarDto(Morris, 5, SEDAN)
```