# MapStruct with Groovy

Tags: groovy, mapstruct

I have a project with groovy classes and I want to use MapStruct for bean mapping. I see in other questions a working solution like this:
[MapStruct with groovy classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69376275/mapstruct-with-groovy-classes)

But for me, when I add:
compileGroovy.groovyOptions.javaAnnotationProcessing = true

the compilation of Groovy stubs fails. I think because I use some AST transformations and @Delegate annotation. My code is statically compiled.

There is a solution? If no, there are similar libraries that works out of the box with Groovy?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: "the compilation of Groovy stubs fails." - Does the Groovy compiler log any information about why compilation failed?

Comment: Yes, I think that the problem is that java compiler run before some AST transformation like AutoImplement, InheritConstructor and Delegate because complain about missing methods in interface or missing constructors...

Comment: " I think that the problem is that java compiler run before some AST transformation like AutoImplement, InheritConstructor and Delegate" - That is interesting.  Is the Java compiler only compiling the stubs that the groovy compiler generates or also compiling Java code that is in the source of the project?

Comment: There is no java code in my codebase. I can do a sample project...

Comment: @JeffScottBrown this is my test repo https://github.com/fmonorchio/test-groovy-mapstruct